# Explicit bound for a definite integral

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, upper-lower-bounds

Let be $$ g_n(x):=\int_0^{x}\frac{t^{2n+1}}{e^t-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(t/x)^2}}dt$$
where we can compute

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}g_n(x)=0\quad$  and $\displaystyle \quad \lim_{x\to \infty}g_n(x)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t^{2n+1}}{e^t-1}dt=\text{Li}_{2 n+2}(1) \Gamma (2 n+2)$

Thus, as $g_n(x)$ exists and is continous $\forall x\in(0,+\infty)$, we can afirma that $g_n(x)$ is bounded in $[0,\infty)$, that is

$$ g_n(x)\le M_n\quad \forall x\in[0,\infty)\quad\text{with $M_n$ not depending on $x$}$$

I wonder if there is any way to compute this constant $M_n$.

---

**NOTE:** Graphics for $n=5$

[image]

Comment: As I currently understand it, you want to find a close upper bound $M_n$ in terms of $n$,  of the limit of $g_n(x)$ as $x$ approaches infinity. Please correct me if I'm wrong though. Also, I assume that $n$ is an integer here?

Comment: Dear Luca, I wanna found a upper bound $M_n$ of $g_n(x)$ in $[0,\infty)$. The limit when $x\to\infty$ is known, but isn't the maximum value because $g_n(x)$ decrese when $x$ tends to $\infty$ (as you can see in the graphic). And yes, $n\in\mathbb{N}$.